# how to call 'this' outside my objects scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, frontend

I have developed some sort of Jcrop initialization for a website, I managed to make my own namespace. Question I have is regarding **this** keyword. Every time I had to access my base object *"aps"* in any callback function I must wrap **this** in a variable (I have chosen word **that**). Is there any better way to do it? For example can I use *call* or *apply* methods? This is just a namespace so I could use simple **aps.***methodName* but for sake of this example, please don't mind it. Here is my source code:

```
var aps;

$(function(){
    aps = function(){

        //  private
        //  variables

        var bgColor = '#f5f5f5';
        var threshold = 370;
        var threshold_width = 800;

        return {
            tmpl                :       $('#jcrop-template').html(),
            upl_cont            :       {},
            form                :       {},
            logo_img            :       new Image(),
            jcrop_api           :       null,
            scaled_logo_url         :       '',
            image_filename          :       '',
            original_image_filename     :       '',
            mime                :       '',
            trueSize            :       '',

            jcrop_init          :       function (oiFrameRes){
                $('#logo_upload_form').find('img').hide();
                this.scaled_logo_url = oiFrameRes.image_url;
                this.logo_url = oiFrameRes.original_image_url;
                this.original_image_filename = oiFrameRes.original_image_filename;
                this.image_filename = oiFrameRes.image_filename;
                this.mime = oiFrameRes.mime;
                this.upl_cont = $('#facebox div#upload-container-d');
                this.logo_img = new Image();
                this.logo_img.that      =   this;
                this.logo_img.name      =   'logo';
                this.logo_img.onload    =   function(){
                    this.true_width=this.width;
                    this.true_height=this.height;
                    this.that.resize_image();
                    this.that.resize_facebox();
                    this.that.display_image();
                }
                this.logo_img.src = this.logo_url;
            },

            resize_image            :       function(){
                this.trueSize = '';
                if(typeof (this.oSettings.trueSize)!=='undefined') delete(this.oSettings.trueSize);
                if (this.logo_img.width > threshold){
                    if (this.logo_img.width > threshold_width){
                        this.trueSize = [ this.logo_img.width, this.logo_img.height ];
                        this.logo_img.height = this.logo_img.height / (this.logo_img.width / threshold_width);
                        this.logo_img.width = threshold_width;
                    }
                }
            },

            resize_facebox          :       function(){
                    var width = (this.logo_img.width > threshold) ? this.logo_img.width : threshold ;
                    $('#facebox').css({
                        left    :   $(window).width() / 2 - width / 2
                    }).
                    find('div.change-size').css({'width': width+30});
            },

            display_image : function (){
                if (this.jcrop_api === null) {
                    $logo_img = $(this.logo_img).css({'display':'block','margin-left':'auto','margin-right':'auto'})
                    if (this.upl_cont.find('#logo-container-d>img').length > 0){
                        if (this.upl_cont.find('#logo-container-d>img').attr('src').length > 0){
                            this.upl_cont.find('#logo-container-d').empty().append($logo_img);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        this.upl_cont.append(this.tmpl).find('#logo-container-d').append($logo_img);
                    }

                    var that = this;
                    if (typeof (this.upl_cont.find('#jcrop-menu1 a').data('events')) === 'undefined'){
                        this.upl_cont.find('#jcrop-menu1 a').click(function(){
                            if (this.href.indexOf('#crop')>-1){
                                $(this).closest('div').hide();
                                that.upl_cont.find('#jcrop-menu2').show();
                                that.setup_crop();
                            }
                            if (this.href.indexOf('#close')>-1){
                                manageIframeResponse();
                            }   
                            location.hash = '';
                            return false;
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this.reset();
                }
            },

            reset : function(){
                $('#jcrop-menu2',this.upl_cont).find('a').unbind('click').end().hide();
                $('#jcrop-coords-f',this.upl_cont).find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){this.value="";}).end().hide();
                $('#jcrop-menu1',this.upl_cont).find('a').unbind('click').end().show();
                this.jcrop_api.destroy();
                this.jcrop_api=null;
                this.display_image();
            },

            send_form : function (){
                var sPost = $(this.form).find('input[name="image_filename"]').val(this.image_filename).end()
                        .find('input[name="original_image_filename"]').val(this.original_image_filename).end()
                        .find('input[name="mime"]').val(this.mime).end()
                        .find('input[name="user_url"]').val($('#logo_upload_base_url').val()).end()
                        .find('input[name="user_key"]').val($('#logo_upload_user_key').val()).end()
                        .serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'iframe_upload.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: sPost,
                    success : function(response){
                        manageIframeResponse();
                    },
                    dataType : 'json'
                });
            },

            setup_crop : function (){

                var that = this;
                if (this.jcrop_api === null) {
                    this.form = this.upl_cont.find('form#jcrop-coords-f').get(0);
                    this.upl_cont.find('#jcrop-menu2>a').click(function(){ that.send_form();return false; });
                    this.updateForm = function (){
                        var c = arguments[0];
                        that.form.x1.value=c.x;
                        that.form.x2.value=c.x2;
                        that.form.y1.value=c.y;
                        that.form.y2.value=c.y2;
                        that.form.h.value=c.h;
                        that.form.w.value=c.w;
                    }

                    this.oSettings.onSelect = this.updateForm;
                    if (typeof (this.trueSize) !== 'string' && $.isArray(this.trueSize)){
                        $.extend(this.oSettings,{'trueSize':this.trueSize});
                    }
                    $('#facebox #logo-container-d>img').Jcrop( this.oSettings, function(){

                        that.jcrop_api = this;
                        var _x1 = (that.logo_img.true_width*0.1).toFixed();
                        var _y1 = (that.logo_img.true_height*0.1).toFixed();
                        var _x2 = (that.logo_img.true_width*0.9).toFixed();
                        var _y2 = (that.logo_img.true_height*0.9).toFixed();
                        that.jcrop_api.setSelect([0,0,that.logo_img.true_width,that.logo_img.true_height]);
                        that.jcrop_api.animateTo([_x1,_y1,_x2,_y2]);
                    });
                }
            },

            updateForm : function (){},

            oSettings : {
                onSelect:'',
                onChange:'',
                keySupport: false,
                bgColor:bgColor,
                aspectRatio:1,
                minSize:[0,0]
            }
        }
    }();

    $(document).bind('afterClose.facebox', function() { 
        if (aps.jcrop_api !=null) {
            aps.jcrop_api.destroy();
            aps.jcrop_api=null;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see a point in assigning the `aps` variable *inside* a ready handler... You're just assigning a function to it, you don't need the ready handler here...

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. You want to invoke that function immediately, so that the return-object is assigned to `aps`...

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what You imply. What is _a ready handler_ and why am I doing it wrong? When I began writing it I just knew that I wanted to encapsulate it, so nothing could access my functions without a namespace.

Comment: A ready handler is a function that is passed in into the `$()` function, like so: `$(function () { ... });`. We use ready handlers to ensure that the web-page (the DOM) is ready, so that our code can operate upon it. In your case, you're just assigning a collection of functions to the `aps` variable - this is independent of the DOM, and can therefore be done immediately; you don't have to place it into the ready handler. Ignore my second comment - I hadn't noticed that you invoked that function via `()`. Usually, when invoking function expressions immediately...

Comment: ... you want to put the function expression in parens, like so `(function () { ... })()` so that it's clear that it's an immediately invoked function expression, and not a regular function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anytime a function is invoked using **function invocation***, the `this` value is set to the global variable (or `undefined` in strict mode)—even if you call the function from a method.  Douglas Crockford has actually described this as a flaw in the language.

Saving the `this` value into a variable that the function will have access to is the standard way of dealing with this.

If you *really* want to control what `this` is in your callback, you could use `apply` or `call`.  Both take as the first argument what you want `this` to be set to.  The difference is that `apply` expects all the function's arguments to be passed as an array, while `call` expects you to list them out individually.

So if, in your ajax callback, you wanted to call `manageIframeResponse`, pass it the ajax call's response (I know your example didn't pass the response, I'm just illustrating how you would do it), and have its `this` value be the same as the current object, you could do:

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
    success : function(response){
        manageIframeResponse.apply(self, [response]); //<--- apply wants your arguments in array form
    }
});
```

Or, since your parameters aren't already in array form, you could more simply use `call`

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
    success : function(response){
        manageIframeResponse.call(self, response); //<---call takes the arguments listed out one at a time
    }
});
```

---

*
There are different ways to invoke a function.

**Function invocation** means you're just calling a function that happens to be in your current scope:

```
foo() //inside foo, this will be the global object (or undefined in strict mode)
```

**Method invocation** means that you're calling a function that's *attached to an object*

```
myObj.foo() //inside foo, this will be myObj
```

Here's an example of where this can trip you up if you're nor careful.

```
function objCreator() {
    var y = "There";

    function privateFunc() {
        alert(y); //alerts There as expected
        alert(this.someField); //undefined:  whoops - this is the global object, 
    }                          //so there's no someField 

    return {
        x: "Hi",
        someField: "blah",
        foo: function () {
            alert(this.x);
            privateFunc();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If you invoke the function as a method, the `this` value refers to the object that owns that method, not the global object.

Comment: The terminology ("function invocation") is misleading or at least confusing to people who haven't read Crockford and/or the spec deeply. Which is most people. :-) Instead, just choose simpler language: "In JavaScript, unlike some other languages, `this` is set entirely by *how* a function is called, not where it's defined." and then you can give examples of the three relevant kinds of invocation (I wouldn't go into constructor functions unless the question used one). My $0.02. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - you're right.  I'll leave the terminology—I think it's important—but I'll illustrate better

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's a good catch, thank you.  I have an edit coming, and I'll combine it with that

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
var aps = (function () {

    // private variables
    var private1;
    var private2;
    var private3;

    var aps = {}; // the core object

    aps.setup_crop = function () {
        // use "aps" to access the core object
        if ( !aps.jcrop_api ) { // etc.
    };

    // define other methods analogously

    return aps;
})();
```